# OpenGL ES 2.0 renderbufferStorage "invalid drawable"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm on the way to move my code from GLKit to OpenGL ES 2.0 because GLKBaseEffect leaks.

I'm in progress, but I face a problem when I link the context and the drawable like this :

```
[_currentContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];
```

This line comes from my shapes (NSObject). Shapes are allocated by a UiView who set the _eaglLayer to self.layer.
The UiView contains the following function :

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

Here is my debug output :

```
2012-08-25 16:04:21.111 P3gameApp[11035:24903] Be layer in setup <P3BoardScene: 0xa072f70; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0xa06bef0>>
-[EAGLContext renderbufferStorage:fromDrawable:]: invalid drawable
2012-08-25 16:04:21.111 P3gameApp[11035:24903] Af layer in setup <P3BoardScene: 0xa072f70; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0xa06bef0>>
```

Comment: I don't know why your drawable is invalid, but the new error you've added is because you're calling setDrawableProperties on the wrong object; you need to set it on the CAEAGLLayer itself; perhaps you need to call it on view.layer?

Comment: Correct, the call on view.layer makes the error disappear. But I have now a black screen, so I don't know if the link context/drawable has been done well.

Comment: I edit the error in the question !

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> SOLVED : Error in my Controller when trying to set drawableProperties. Error comes from my view.
>
> ```
> [P3BoardScene setDrawableProperties:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdb99090
> ```
>
> Error comes from my view again
>
> ```
> [P3Scene setEnableSetNeedsDisplay:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x495d40
> ```